# Bash script to run perforce4 on startup with -C1 argument via daemon calls daemon config instead of launching P4 server with -C1 arg

Tags: bash, perforce, init.d

So, I've got this bit of a script trying to launch a P4 server in init.d

When I run this, daemon parses "p4start" and outputs:

daemon --user=perforce -d -C1

Unfortunately, daemon has decided that -C1 will be parsed as a command to Daemon instead of an argument to pass to p4d. So I get this error:

Invalid --config option argument 1: no such file or directory

Is there a good way to get around this?

Thanks!

```
  p4start="p4d -d -C1"
  p4stop="p4 admin stop"
  p4user=perforce

  case "$1" in
  start)
    log_action_begin_msg "Starting Perforce Server"
    daemon --user=$p4user $p4start;
    ;;
```

Comment: What would the desired working daemon command look like when you ran it from the shell prompt?

Comment: "daemon --user=perforce p4d -d -C1", or, if you're asking the p4d command:

p4d -d -C1

Comment: Then I don't get it. Those are the same commands; both will work, or both won't. Is p4d really an argument you can pass to the daemon command? Or should they be separate commands? What if you quote it with `daemon --user=$p4user "$p4start"`?

Comment: Aah. My apologies. I've fiddled with it more and at least gotten more information. Let me try to be more clear:

The intention here is to have daemon run the command "p4d" with the arguments "-d -C1" as user "perforce"

Currently, daemon is "consuming" the -d and -C1 arguments, which should be passed to "p4d". I am not sure why this is happening, though.

p4d is the perforce server, -d and -C1 are arguments for the perforce server. They should NOT be used by daemon.

Comment: does your "daemon" command accept `--` to indicate end of options?